# Use a global string variable in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

This question was probably asked. But I haven't found any satisfying answer:

I have a web app which tries to work as a local Dropbox. So its very important to know what current folder I am currently at. I have many **nested components** which can change the current folder, and **every time the current folder is changed, the website should be re-rendered**.

What is the best way to solve this problem ? Until now I tried to pass down the state to the child components but the code looks ugly. And I want to avoid using global variable, actually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to avoid prop drilling and have a global context in your app storing things like current path. It depends on what you really want, but I think a global context/store would help you.